# QTableView c++ sort when header clicking

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtableview, qsqlquery

I need to sort a column in my table when I click to header of column.
But now I can't, that's my table:

[image]

There is no action if I click to the header.

That's my c++ QT code:

```
    void showTable()
{
    connOpen();
    QSqlQueryModel * myModel=new QSqlQueryModel();
    QSqlQuery select;
    if (!select.exec("select * from tab")) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), select.lastError().text());
    }
    else {
        myModel->setQuery(select);
        ui->tableView->setModel(myModel);
    }
    connClose();
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to do 2 things:

- Enable the [`sortingEnabled`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setSortingEnabled) property of the view so that the user can have control of the order by clicking on the horizontal header.
- Use [`QSortFilterProxyModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) to handle the order relationship.

---

```
void showTable()
{
    connOpen();
    QSqlQueryModel * myModel=new QSqlQueryModel(ui->tableView);
    QSqlQuery select;
    if (!select.exec("select * from tab")) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), select.lastError().text());
    }
    else {
        myModel->setQuery(select);
        QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(myModel); // create proxy
        proxyModel->setSourceModel(myModel);
        ui->tableView->setSortingEnabled(true); // enable sortingEnabled
        ui->tableView->setModel(proxyModel);
    }
    connClose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just enable the sorting by:

```
filesTable->setSortingEnabled(true);
```

It worked for me. I use qt 5.15 and QTableWidget instead of QTableView.

Here is example with your code:

```
    void showTable()
{
    ui->tableView->setSortingEnabled(true); //
    connOpen();
    QSqlQueryModel * myModel=new QSqlQueryModel();
    QSqlQuery select;
    if (!select.exec("select * from tab")) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), select.lastError().text());
    }
    else {
        myModel->setQuery(select);
        ui->tableView->setModel(myModel);
    }
    connClose();
}
```

You can add this properties once you create table. This method is inherit from QTableWidget Class.

Comment: Upvoted because I think you've got the answer, but you should expand this answer before the OP accepts it. Specifically, they don't have a `filesTable` in their listing. Where and how would they call the `setSortingEnabled()` method in their listing?

Comment: @MatthewCole I have completed the answer.

Comment: looks much better. Hopefully it works for the OP and they accept it if it does.